# Gallery and Colorbox group images

Tags: jquery, image, gallery, colorbox, rel

I have a little gallery:

- Big photo
- Little thumbs at the bottom

When a user click on a thumb the big photo change and when you click it ColorBox load, so far so good.

Now i want that when a user is in the ColorBox he can navigate trough the images with the next a prev arrows but how can i do this? With the normal 'rel: 'gallery'' it wont work?

**Here is my js**:

```
$("#wrapper #right #detail #photo ul li .thumb").click(function() {
    var image = $(this).attr("rel");
    $('#image').hide();
    $('#image').fadeIn('fast');
    $('#image').html('<table><tr><td><a href="' + image + '" class="gallery"><img src="' + image + '" alt="" /></a></td></tr></table>');
    return false;
});

$('#wrapper #right #detail #big #image').on('click', 'a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.colorbox({
        transition: 'elastic',
        href: this.href,
        rel: 'gallery',
        speed: 200,
        opacity: 0.4,
        scalePhotos : true,
        maxWidth : '800px',
        maxHeight : '700px'
    });
});
```

**And the HTML**:

```
<div id="photo">
    <div id="big"><div id="image"><table><tr><td><a href="gfx/detail/1.jpg" class="gallery"><img src="gfx/detail/1.jpg" alt="" /></a></td></tr></table></div></div>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" rel="gfx/detail/1.jpg" class="thumb gallery"><img src="gfx/detail/1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="gfx/detail/2.jpg" class="thumb gallery"><img src="gfx/detail/2.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="gfx/detail/3.jpg" class="thumb gallery"><img src="gfx/detail/3.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Can somewone help me so that colorbox makes his next and prev gallery?

Comment: To group your images for that they have to have the same `rel` value.

Comment: In the example of ColorBox they have the same class not the rel?

Answer (score 1):

Try initialize group before calling `colorbox`:

```
$('.gallery').colorbox({ rel:'gallery' });
```

Any success?

Answer (score 0):

The "rel" property of colorbox refers to the "rel" attribute on the `<a>` tag.  Try:

```
<div id="photo">
<div id="big"><div id="image"><table><tr><td><a href="gfx/detail/1.jpg" class="gallery">    <img src="gfx/detail/1.jpg" alt="" /></a></td></tr></table></div></div>

<ul>
    <li><a href="gfx/detail/1.jpg" rel="gallery" class="thumb gallery"><img src="gfx/detail/1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="gfx/detail/2.jpg" rel="gallery" class="thumb gallery"><img src="gfx/detail/2.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="gfx/detail/3.jpg" rel="gallery" class="thumb gallery"><img src="gfx/detail/3.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```